# What is a type "t" in an inferred Haskell type signature?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I wrote a function `f`, which I use in a `foldM`:

```
foldM (f xs) [] ids
...
f xs acc id = case lookup id xs of
    Just x -> return $ acc ++ [(id, x)]
    Nothing -> throwError $ TypeError "Cannot project nonexisting field"
```

the type signature I wrote for it is:

```
[(String, Value)] -> [(String, Value)] -> String -> EvalMonad [(String, Value)]
```

then I decided to delete the type signature, since the function is simple and descriptive enough as it is. When I used hdevtools to get the inferred type, I got

```
[(t, t)] -> [(t, t)] -> t -> m [(t, t)]
```

What is this? I am guessing that t is different from the usual `a` or `b` you commonly see. The first and second element of the tuple are not the same type (no, SValue is not a type synonym of String), while this signature implies that constraint. Also, why is there no class constraint on the monad m? I am not using the whole EvalMonad stack here, but `m` should at least be an instance of `MonadError`.

Comment: I think you dropped a constraint when copy/pasting that type. You should have got the type `Monad m => [(t, t)] -> [(t, t)] -> t -> m [(t, t)]`.  The difference is rather important.

Comment: nope, that's what hdevtools prints. I figured that in the end ghci must get things right or I would get a segfault or similar, but I am wondering why the mistake. AFAIK, hdevtools and ghc-mod are what people use for type inference. It's very useful, but I can't have it derp out as soon as I analyze a nontrivial expression...

Comment: Looks like this is [this ghc-mod bug](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/69).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ghci to check the inferred type of your code, like so:

```
f typeError xs acc id = case lookup id xs of
    Just x -> return $ acc ++ [(id, x)]
    Nothing -> throwError $ typeError "Cannot project nonexisting field"
```

(note that I made the fixed `TypeError` into an extra argument `typeError` so I didn't have to have a definition for it)

The type I got was:

```
f :: (Eq t, MonadError e m) =>
     ([Char] -> e) -> [(t, t1)] -> [(t, t1)] -> t -> m [(t, t1)]
```

So I'm not sure why you're getting something a type with `[(t, t)]`, or without the constraints. `t` in a type signature is indeed the same as `a` or `b`; in a type, any identifier starting with a lowercase letter is a type variable, and multiple repetitions of a single such identifier within a single type represent the same type variable.

Comment: I'm happy that at least ghc gets it right :-) So this is a bug in hdevtools?

Comment: That's my impression, yes.